# the basic use of foreign keys and triggers in mysql databases

Tags: mysql, foreign-key-relationship, database-trigger

I'm working on learning mySQL. I'm using a mixture of mySQL workbench and Linux terminal to get my head around it. I'm struggling with foreign keys and triggers. I think I might have misunderstood one or both of these and that's what is causing the confusion. I'm hoping someone can not just provide code to fix the problem but explain to me what I'm misunderstanding.

I've got two small tables that I've created called Organisation and People. In this scenario they have a one to many relationship: many people can work for one organisation, but one person can only work for one organisation. I therefore insert the organisation tables primary key 'organisation_id' into the people table as a foreign key using the same name 'organisation_id'. I do this so that I can use the foreign key in the people table to keep track of who works for which organisation. My aim is then to have the foreign key in people update automatically using a trigger when I add new people to this table, thus keeping track of who works for which organisation. I just can't figure out how to do this. If I add an entry to the people table how can the table figure out the missing cell in it's row? Have I misunderstood one-to-many relations and foreign keys? Can anyone show me how to code this correctly and tell me where I've gone wrong? I know this is probably such a basic question but I need a help.

my tables code from mySQL workbench is below:

```
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `learning` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 ;
USE `learning` ;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `learning`.`organisation` (
`organisation_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
`org_name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
`org_website` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`organisation_id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `learning`.`people` (
`people_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `name` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
`job` VARCHAR(45) NULL, 
 `organisation_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`people_id`),
 INDEX `fk_organisation_id_idx` (`organisation_id` ASC),
 CONSTRAINT `fk_organisation_id`
 FOREIGN KEY (`organisation_id`)
 REFERENCES `learning`.`organisation` (`organisation_id`)
 ON DELETE NO ACTION
 ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
 ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Comment: Your many-to-one seems correct, as for the trigger, could you elaborate 'If I add an entry to the people table how can the table figure out the missing cell in it's row?'

Comment: I mean if I update the table to add a new row how do I get the trigger statement to auto-fill the people.organisation_id cell in the newly inserted row. I'm figuring it's an AFTER INSERT statement but the syntax is confusing me a little. I need to have a think about what shadow said below.

Comment: A new row in organisation? Or a new row in the people table?

Comment: a new row in the people table. So I add their details but the database auto-fills the people.organisation_id cell based on the string value I enter via whatever interface I put on top of the database

Comment: You're missing something here I think. I assume your 'interface' has a selection with organization names, and someone can choose an organization from that interface. Now what you want the actual value to be is the ID of the organization, not the 'name' which you only use to show a list of the organizations on your interface, if that makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You understood the concept of foreign keys correctly, but not its application.

Yes, it helps you to associate `people` with the `organisation` and makes sure that you can only enter a valid `organisation_id` into the `people` table (valid=exists in `organisation` table).

However, the database cannot figure it out on its own to which organisation a people belongs to. This is something you need to provide in the insert itself.

In the application that uses this database there would be a form for adding `people` to the database. On that form you need to provide which organisation the user belongs to.

The `on delete` and `on update` clauses in the foreign key definition actually apply to the `organisation` table: if the `organisation_id` field is deleted / updated in the `organisation` table, then what actions should be taken in the `people` table.

Comment: Thanks Shadow. I think I'm with you. For example, if it was accessed via a Java application their might be a field marked *Organisation. The data entered by the user would then be looked up in the organisation table and the organisation.organisation_id value would be copied across as the value for people.organisation_id. Have I understood correctly? Is there a way to make this automation take place on the database end rather than have the scripting handling the form do it? If I was doing this via Java and the database was on a server somewhere wouldn't this make it all run slow?

Comment: Yes, you got it right. Again, how would you make this decision on the database level, if the decision is not known to the database?

Comment: That makes me think that if the integrity of the relationships between the tables in a database comes down to the logic of the interface code, why use a declared foreign key? For example, in my tables, if I didn't have the Foreign Key people.organisation_id and I had instead another column of INTs called 'employer', which was not declared as a Foreign Key, and I used the interface Code to copy the organisation.organisation_id into the people.employer column for each new entry. How would that be different? What am I not understanding?

Comment: Foreign keys are there to protect the integrity of your data regardless how the data is entered into the database. Btw back in the old days mysql used the same reasoning for a while to justify why mysql did not support foreign keys.